# How to add double quote in values inside a PHP variable and convert it to an array

Tags: php

I have this variable `$numbers` and it contains values like this way-> `1,2,3,4,5`

So when I echo this `$number` I naturally see like this-> `1,2,3,4,5`

Now, Could you please tell me how to convert the variable "`$number`" like following

```
$topic=array("1","2","3","4","5");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) which splits a string on a delimiter and returns an array. You don't need to add quotes around the numbers.

```
$topic = explode(',', $numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

lots of typos so hard to understand but I think you're talking about the fact the array made string datatypes when it made the array right? Everything else you already mention (but typo'd to death right?)

```
$number = array(1,2,3,4,5); //"1","2", are string litterals
foreach ($numbers as $number){
    echo "<p>". $number . "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

oh I see what he meant now - [explode](http://php.net/explode) (used to be MUCH EASIER to use when it was called [split](http://php.net/split) -  which is a better name IMO but has no reciprocal relationship to [implode](http://php.net/implode))

Comment: When saying things that aren't answers to the question, please make a comment on one of the existing answers, or on the question, instead of making a new answer. And yeah, the question was very hard to understand.