# PHP Convert String Array to Single Quote for each Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an simple question how to add single quote `'` to every array.

Example:

```
$a = array("1,2,3,4,5,6");
```

then convert it to be:

```
$a = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
```

Let me know your suggestion.

Comment: just explode it then cast all into string

Comment: array is always double quotes

Comment: Any example of that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add double quote in values inside a PHP variable and convert it to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790749/how-to-add-double-quote-in-values-inside-a-php-variable-and-convert-it-to-an-arr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = explode(',', array_shift($a));
```

Comment: Hi I think you should unedit your answer, OP wasn't really clear and your previous one might be the solution he needs...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) function.

You can use it like this:

```
$newArray = explode("," , $a[0]);
```

This is accordingly to your sample return.

```
$a = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
```

If what you need is this:

```
$a = array("'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'"); // Not the same
```

@Matei Mihai has answered that.